# Detect if player is hit by shadow unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, light

I'm making a 2D game that the player can't touch the light source, so I typed the light code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shadow2DLight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float range = 5.0f;
    public float intensity = 1.0f;
    public Color color = Color.white;

    //Internal fields, cache V and P matrix for this frame.
    internal Matrix4x4[] V = new Matrix4x4[4];  //Four matricies for right, down, left ,up
    internal Matrix4x4 P;

    public static List<Shadow2DLight> lights = new List<Shadow2DLight>();
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void OnEnable() {
        lights.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        lights.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

then the block code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class Shadow2DCaster : MonoBehaviour
{
    private new SpriteRenderer renderer;
    private Mesh shadowMesh;
    private void Awake() {
        renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        shadowMesh = new Mesh();
        shadowMesh.vertices = renderer.sprite.vertices.Select(t => new Vector3(t.x, t.y, 0.0f)).ToArray();
        var originalTriangles = renderer.sprite.triangles;
        var newTriangleIndicies = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < originalTriangles.Length / 3; i++) {
            newTriangleIndicies.Add(originalTriangles[3 * i]);
            newTriangleIndicies.Add(originalTriangles[3 * i + 1]);

            newTriangleIndicies.Add(originalTriangles[3 * i + 1]);
            newTriangleIndicies.Add(originalTriangles[3 * i + 2]);

            newTriangleIndicies.Add(originalTriangles[3 * i + 2]);
            newTriangleIndicies.Add(originalTriangles[3 * i]);
        }
        shadowMesh.SetIndices(newTriangleIndicies.ToArray(), MeshTopology.Lines, 0);
        shadowMesh.UploadMeshData(true);
    }

    public Mesh GetLineMesh() {
        return shadowMesh;
    }

    public static List<Shadow2DCaster> casters = new List<Shadow2DCaster>();
    private static Dictionary<Sprite, Mesh> shadowMeshCache;

    private void OnEnable() {
        casters.Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        casters.Remove(this);
    }
}
```

then the Shadow2DPipeline code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class Shadow2DPipeline : MonoBehaviour {
    private Material shadowMapMaterial;
    private Material lightingMaterial;
    private RenderTexture shadowMap;
    private CommandBuffer shadowMapCmdBuffer;
    private CommandBuffer lightingCmdBuffer;
    private MaterialPropertyBlock propertyBlock;
    private Mesh lightingQuad;

    private const int MAX_LIGHTS_COUNT = 64;
    private const int SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH = 256;
    private int ShadowMapHeight {
        get {
            return MAX_LIGHTS_COUNT * 4;
        }
    }

    private void Start() {
        propertyBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        shadowMap = new RenderTexture(SHADOW_MAP_WIDTH, ShadowMapHeight, 0, RenderTextureFormat.RFloat, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);
        shadowMap.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
        shadowMap.antiAliasing = 1;
        shadowMap.anisoLevel = 0;
        shadowMapMaterial = new Material(Resources.Load<Shader>("2DShadowMap"));
        lightingMaterial = new Material(Resources.Load<Shader>("2DAdditiveLight"));
        {
            lightingQuad = new Mesh();
            lightingQuad.vertices = new Vector3[] {
                new Vector3(-1.0f, -1.0f),
                new Vector3(-1.0f, 1.0f),
                new Vector3(1.0f, -1.0f),
                new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f),
            };
            lightingQuad.triangles = new int[] {
                0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3
            };
            lightingQuad.UploadMeshData(true);
        }
    }

    private void OnPreRender() {

        var cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
        var shadowCasters = Shadow2DCaster.casters;
        var lights = Shadow2DLight.lights;

        {   //Update shadow map rendering command buffer.
            if (shadowMapCmdBuffer == null) {
                shadowMapCmdBuffer = new CommandBuffer();
                cam.AddCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.BeforeForwardOpaque, shadowMapCmdBuffer);
            }
            shadowMapCmdBuffer.Clear();
            /*
             * Shadow caster mesh is line-strip mesh.
             * 
             * In shadow map, each 4 rows belong to one light, corresponding to depth in (0, 90), (90, 180)...(270, 360).
             * 
             * To render shadow mesh at correct position, a naive MVP matrix is used.
             * Then, after transforming to clip space, manually edit y component to the corresponding row.
             */
            shadowMapCmdBuffer.SetRenderTarget(shadowMap);
            shadowMapCmdBuffer.ClearRenderTarget(true, true, Color.black);
            shadowMapCmdBuffer.SetGlobalVector(ShaderKeys.ShadowMap2DSize, new Vector4(1.0f / shadowMap.width, 1.0f / shadowMap.height, shadowMap.width, shadowMap.height));

            //Calculate V and P for each light.
            foreach (var light in lights) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {   //four directions.

                    //This TRS here calculates light->world matrix.
                    //The Quaternion.Euler(90.0f * i, 90.0f, 270.0f) aligns light to right, down, left, up.
                    //-1.0f in z-component in scale corrects camera forward direction.
                    var V = Matrix4x4.TRS(light.transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(90.0f * i, 90.0f, 270.0f), new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f));
                    //Inverse it, so it's a world->light matrix.
                    V = V.inverse;

                    var P = Matrix4x4.Perspective(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.01f, 10.0f);
                    P = GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix(P, true);
                    light.V[i] = V;
                    light.P = P;
                }
            }

            foreach (var shadowCaster in shadowCasters) {
                var M = shadowCaster.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
                for (int iLight = 0; iLight < Mathf.Min(MAX_LIGHTS_COUNT, lights.Count); iLight++) {
                    //Render shadow map of each light, by drawing shadow line mesh onto the shadowmap.
                    for (int iDir = 0; iDir < 4; iDir++) { //Four directions, right, down, left, up.

                        var light = lights[iLight];
                        var MVP = light.P * light.V[iDir] * M;

                        shadowMapCmdBuffer.SetGlobalMatrix(ShaderKeys.ShadowMap2DMVP, MVP);
                        float writeClipSpaceY = (iLight * 4 + iDir + 0.5f) / (float)(ShadowMapHeight);
                        shadowMapCmdBuffer.SetGlobalFloat(ShaderKeys.ShadowMap2DWriteRow, (writeClipSpaceY - 0.5f) * 2.0f);
                        shadowMapCmdBuffer.DrawMesh(shadowCaster.GetLineMesh(), Matrix4x4.identity /*Use our own MVP matrix*/, shadowMapMaterial);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        {   //Update lighting command buffer.

            //Draw a "light quad" for each light.
            //
            //There's lots of ways to add light to 2d scene.
            //Here we just use an additive "layer"
            //Edit to what you like.
            if (lightingCmdBuffer == null) {
                lightingCmdBuffer = new CommandBuffer();
                lightingCmdBuffer.name = "2D Lighting";
                cam.AddCommandBuffer(CameraEvent.AfterForwardAlpha, lightingCmdBuffer);
            }
            lightingCmdBuffer.Clear();

            lightingCmdBuffer.SetGlobalTexture(ShaderKeys.ShadowMap2D, shadowMap);
            for (int iLight = 0; iLight < Mathf.Min(MAX_LIGHTS_COUNT, lights.Count); iLight++) {
                var light = lights[iLight];
                lightingCmdBuffer.SetGlobalVector(ShaderKeys.LightParams, new Vector4(light.range, light.intensity, light.transform.position.x, light.transform.position.y));
                lightingCmdBuffer.SetGlobalVector(ShaderKeys.LightColor, light.color);

                lightingCmdBuffer.SetGlobalFloat(ShaderKeys.ShadowMap2DLightIndex, (float)iLight);
                for (int iVP = 0; iVP < ShaderKeys._ShadowMap2DVP.Length; iVP++) {
                    lightingCmdBuffer.SetGlobalMatrix(ShaderKeys._ShadowMap2DVP[iVP], light.P * light.V[iVP]);
                }
                var M = Matrix4x4.TRS(light.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one * light.range);
                lightingCmdBuffer.SetGlobalMatrix(ShaderKeys.LightM, M);
                lightingCmdBuffer.DrawMesh(lightingQuad, M, lightingMaterial);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ShaderKeys {
        public static int ShadowMap2DSize = Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DSize");
        public static int ShadowMap2DMVP = Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DMVP");
        public static int ShadowMap2DWriteRow = Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DWriteRow"); 
        public static int ShadowMap2D = Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2D");
        public static int ShadowMap2DLightIndex = Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DLightIndex");
        public static int[] _ShadowMap2DVP = new int[] {
            Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DVP_Right"),
            Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DVP_Down"),
            Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DVP_Left"),
            Shader.PropertyToID("_ShadowMap2DVP_Up"),
        };
        public static int LightM = Shader.PropertyToID("_LightM");
        public static int LightParams = Shader.PropertyToID("_LightParams");
        public static int LightColor = Shader.PropertyToID("_LightColor");
    }
}
```

but how i can detect if the player touch the light??
you can get the source code from here : https://github.com/yangrc1234/Unity2DShadowMap

preview from here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGgr2.gif

Comment: Have you considered simply raytracing from your object to the light? If the ray hits something before it reaches the light then the object is in shadow, else it's in light?

Comment: Hi @Jake, thanks for your reply, but I don't get it can you explain more, please?

Comment: Okay, I'll explain further in an answer

Answer (score 0):

So one solution would be not to directly detect any shadows, but leverage the essential properties of shadows to get the same effect.

An area that is in shadow is in shadow because there is an opaque object between it and the light source.

An area that is in light is in light because there are no objects between it and the light source.

Therefore you can simply detect if there is an object between your player and the light source using a raycast and use that information to determine if you are in shadow/light.

Very roughly:

```
Vector3 playerToLight = light.transform.position - player.transform.position;
float distance = playerToLight.magnitude;
vctor3 origin = player.transform.position;
vector3 direction = playerToLight.normalized;

if(Physics.Raycast(origin,direction,distance)){
    // in shadow
} else {
    // in light
}
```